# Trying to convert string into array which has a key and a value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
{"Name?":"Hamz","Why do you want to join the team?":"Test","Your Date of Birth?":"2000-05-02","Your Age?":"25"}
```

This is the string I have, "question":"answer" then there each split by a comma.

Would anyone know how I would go about doing this in php?

Comment: This looks like JSON, so try [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Note that you need to read a bit of the manual to figure out how to make an array instead of an object.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Tried json_decode but it comes back NULL.

Comment: No, it does not. See: https://3v4l.org/62dfY

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Figured it out, I was storing it in the database incorrectly which is why it wouldnt work when I was trying to json_decode it, but now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use json_decode as it is json:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode